# Xamarin Forms: How to use Embedded Resources in PCL Project for Image

Tags: image, mvvm, xamarin, imagesource, xamarin.forms

I have 4 Images in my **Resources** Directory into my **Portable Project** and i would like to use them directly for an **ImageSource** (because i need to bind it).

```
ImageSource myImageSource = ImageSource.FromResource("resources.image.png");
```

I tried this but it doesn't recognize the path. How can i use my images for an ImageSource ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, my bad i forgot the name of my project before the Resources directory

```
ImageSource myImageSource = ImageSource.FromResource("NameOfProject.Resources.image.png");
```